# Passing a value into a function without being listed as a formal argument?

Tags: c

In stdlib.h,

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size,
            int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));
```

will it be possible to pass the following function as `compar`,

```
int compareMyType (const void * a, const void * b, float c)
{
  float tmp = f((MyType*)a,  (MyType*)b, c );  // f is some function
  if (tmp < 0) return -1;
  if (tmp == 0) return 0;
  if (tmp > 0) return 1;
}
```

If no, without declaring `c` to be a global variable, is there some way? Thanks!

Comment: But how would `qsort` pass the parameter?

Comment: good question. I would like `c` to be able to change when calling qsort at different times.

Answer (score 3):

Create a proxy-function that will be compatible with `qsort` and in its body it will call your function:

```
int myCompare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    float c = ...;

    return compareMyType(a, b, c);
}

...

qsort(..., myCompare);
```

Comment: `function`? I think you meant `int`.

Comment: Yes, I meant `int`. Fixed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> will it be possible to pass the following function as compar

No. Pointers to functions with only the exact same signatures are compatible. Your `compar` function must have the signature

```
int compar(const void *, const void *);
```

You can write your own qsort function with custom `compar` function prototype or you can encapsulate your compare function of different signature within a function of the above signature which simply calls your compare function.

Answer (score 0):

No, function signature doesn't match.
compareMyType (const void * a, const void * b, float c) and int (*compar)(const void*,const void*)

You can pack the variable c in structure and typecast the structure pointer to void pointer and pass it. That is the main advantage of using void pointer in the first place.

Comment: you actually can't. More correctly, cou can, but it will not work. The poihters will be used by `qsort()` later in the process to swap elements which will probably end up in a mess.